# My development computer is running a newer .Net version, but my Windows 2019 VPS is running a slightly older version. Is it safe to deploy on the VPS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, windows, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2022 on my development computer and my ASP.net MVC application is targeting the .Net 4.8 framework. I want to deploy my ASP.net MVC application to a Windows Server 2019 VPS. So I ran 'reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\full" /v version' on my development computer and on my Windows Server 2019 VPS to check to see which version of .Net they are both running.

My development computer is running .Net 4.8.04161.  The Windows Server 2019 VPS I want to deploy to is running .Net 4.8.03761, which is a slightly older version than the version of .Net on my development computer.  I also tried to upgrade my Windows Server 2019 VPS to the 4.8.1 .Net framework, but unfortunately, [the 4.8.1 .Net framework is not supported on Windows 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-framework-481/). I also went to Windows Update on my Windows Server 2019 VPS and tried to check for updates, but it said everything was up to date on my Windows Server 2019 VPS.  So I guess 4.8.03761 is the latest version of .Net that Windows Server 2019 will update to.

So my question is, since my development computer is running .Net 4.8.04161, and my Windows 2019 VPS is running .Net 4.8.03761, which is a slightly older version than my development computer, is it safe to deploy my ASP.net MVC application from my development computer to my Windows Server 2019 VPS?  I am worried about bugs or other issues, because the Windows Server 2019 is running a slightly older version of .Net than my development computer (and I have tried what I can to update my Windows Server 2019 VPS to a newer version of .Net and I haven't succeeded).

Comment: Hi, @Programmer Joe . Did my answer solve your problem? If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

Comment: @HuiLiu-MSFT Sorry for being slow. I was just waiting for other answers but none of them came.  I have checked your answer as the best answer.  FYI, for others that are wondering, I did some testing on my Asp.net MVC application on the Windows 2019 server and based on my testing so far, running  a .Net 4.8.04161 ASP.Net MVC application on a Windows 2019 server that is using .Net 4.8.03761 seems to work - I did not encounter any bugs or errors so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, between a major version and a minor version, there is little change. Unless there are some changes in the code, otherwise, it will basically have no effect

You can check the version update of .NET in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#net-framework-481).